# Can't access json params in middleware when using delete http verb

Tags: json, laravel-5, middleware, http-delete

I'm working with Laravel 5. I have a middleware that works fine with GET, POST and PUT http verbs, but when I intercept a DELETE route I can't access the json body params, just the url ones.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {

        // Incorrect data or user does not exist
        if( !$request->input('csrf_token') || !$request->input('user_id') 
            || !( $user = User::find( $request->input('user_id') ) ) ){
            return json_encode(array('status' => env('STATUS_AUTH_ERROR'), 'exception' => 'TokenMismatchException'));
        }        
        // Incorrect token for user
        $user_token = $user->remember_token;
        if( !isset( $user_token ) || $user_token !== $request->input('csrf_token') ){
            return json_encode(array('status' => env('STATUS_AUTH_ERROR'), 'exception' => 'TokenMismatchException'));
        }            
        return $next($request);
    }
```

`$request->input('user_id')` returns me NULL. Why?